# Measurability of $\int f(x,\bullet) d\nu$ (product space)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm self-studying a set of notes on measure theory. For [this chapter](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch5.pdf), the author said that he is not going to prove every theorem, and I have some trouble with this particular one:

**Theorem 5.15**. Let $(X,A,\mu)$ and $(Y,B,\nu)$ be measure spaces and $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. [Let's just do $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity - not much difference]. Then $f_x:=f(x,\bullet)$ is measurable for every $x$ and similarly for $f_y$. [I have figured this part out.] Moreover, if $(X,A,\mu)$ and $(Y,B,\nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite, then the functions $g(x):=\int f_x d\nu$ and $h(y):=\int f_y d\mu$ are measurable. [This is the part where I have no idea.]

For most of the notes I have been able to figure the proof out or find something online, but I think I need some help on this one.

**Edit:** Thinking further, I realized that it is possible for $g(x)$ to be undefined for some values of $x$, but they should be only for a set of measure zero, so arbitrarily define $g(x)$ for these values of $x$. Same for $h$.

Comment: Start by showing it for $f=\mathbf{1}_{C\times D}$ for $C\in A$ and $D\in B$. Then extend to the more general case.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a difficult exercise if there are no hints.  You start by proving it for f= a characteristic function of a measurable set.  To prove this special case, you need to know that the "monotone class" generated by an algebra of sets is the sigma algebra generated by those sets.  Let $S$ be the set of subsets of $X\times Y$ whose characteristic functions make the statement true.  S contains all finite disjoint unions of "rectangular sets" (sets of the form $A\times B$), an algebra. S is also a "monotone class," so it contains the sigma algebra generated by the rectangular sets.

Comment: Oh but to show S is a monotone class, you should first assume the measures are finite. In particular, I think you will use finiteness of the measure to show S is closed under intersections of nested sets. Then use $\sigma$ finiteness to remove that requirement.  Finally since any measurable function is an increasing point-wise limit of linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets, you can use Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem to get the statement for general f.